# Moving plugins to parent pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have two child pom and 1 parent pom,I moved common dependencies to parent and after setting up relative path build succeeded and now I  moved common plugins to parent pom and it's throwing me an error,here's the code snippet for parent pom.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${dependency.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                      <id>copy-test-license</id>
                      <goals>
                         <goal>copy</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                      <configuration>
                         <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                               <groupId>com.cerner.clover</groupId>
                               <artifactId>clover</artifactId>
                               <version>${clover.license.version}</version>
                               <type>license</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                         </artifactItems>
                         <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                         <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                      </configuration>
                   </execution>
                   <execution>
                      <id>copy-pre-site-license</id>
                      <goals>
                         <goal>copy</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <phase>pre-site</phase>
                      <configuration>
                         <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                               <groupId>com.cerner.clover</groupId>
                               <artifactId>clover</artifactId>
                               <version>${clover.license.version}</version>
                               <type>license</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                         </artifactItems>
                         <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                         <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                      </configuration>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
             </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
```

The error is:

```
build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin must be a valid version but is '${dependency.plugin.version}'.
```

I understood that problem is created due to not mentioning version. How to solve this?

Comment: As mentioned by @bambula, you must also move the property for the plugin versions from the child poms to your parent pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have something like this in your parent pom:

```
<properties>
...
   <dependency.plugin.version>your-plugin-version</dependency.plugin.version>
...
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you,issue is solved now but I would like to know one more thing. The parent pom which I created checks automatically maven repo for plugins but I want my parent pom to check it from my orginazation repo to get plugins,how do I do that? As it checks maven repo it throws an error saying that specified path doesn't contain the plugin.

Comment: check https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html